# Merge multiple xlsx and xls files into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have many xlsx and xls files in a folder containing 2-3 worksheets in each file. I want to merge all these files into one workbook. I have a sample code but it is not merging xlsx file, it is picking only xls files of the selected folder. Sample code is mentioned below. Help me

```
Sub MergeFiles ()
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFD As FileDialog
    Dim mainWb, sourceWb As Workbook
    Dim tempWS As Worksheet
    Set mainWb = Workbooks.Add 'Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFD.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFD.Show

    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFD.SelectedItems.Count
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFD.SelectedItems(i)
        Set sourceWb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWS In sourceWb.Worksheets
            tempWS.Copy after:=mainWb.Sheets(mainWb.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWS

        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWb.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do it with VBA Macro.. Merge files with a simple VBA macro
Here are some tips to get you sorted https://professor-excel.com/merge-excel-files-combine-workbooks-one-file/

Comment: Already used but could not succeed!

Answer (score -1):

Your code does work without any problems with a small amount of xls, xlsx and xlsb files.

I've tried with 24 different files.

```
Sub MergeFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' **** Gain some performance?

    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFD As FileDialog
    Dim mainWb, sourceWb As Workbook
    Dim tempWS As Worksheet
    Set mainWb = Workbooks.Add 'Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFD.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFD.Show

    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFD.SelectedItems.Count
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFD.SelectedItems(i)
        Set sourceWb = ActiveWorkbook

        ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True       '****** Uncomment to get more feedback
        ' mainWb.Activate
        ' mainWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        ' mainWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = sourceWb.Name
        ' Debug.Print sourceWb.Name
        ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWS In sourceWb.Worksheets
            tempWS.Copy after:=mainWb.Sheets(mainWb.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWS

        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWb.Close

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' **** Gain some performance?

End Sub
```